# How to call a static list from another class where the list return type is not supported

Tags: c#

I am trying to call a static list from one common static class (which is passed as argument) to another method in another class, where the caller class doesnt support the return type of the static list.

How can I make the call from the caller and pass the list as argument without worrying that the caller doesnt have the return type support? Following is what im trying to achieve:

```
public static ListHolder
{
    public static List<type> abc;
}

// Caller Class which doesnt have "type" supported
public class Caller
{
    public void Method()
    {
        FillMe(ListHolder.ABC);
    }
}    

// Adaptor Method -- here the list type is supported
public class Adaptor
{
    public void FillMe(Holder.ABC)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your syntax for the definition of the FillMe method is not right. Read up on how to pass parameters to methods.

Comment: hi and welcome! I like that you added a code example, but this is all quite vauge - maybe you could improve your answer a bit?

Comment: What do you mean by supported? There is no such concept. Do you mean known? If so, can't you have a shared base type or interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another work around for this.
Instead of doing all these, I created some static variables with Enumurator for the variable names, now this enumerator name is passed as reference.